OpenBook or Liquidity Pool
I'm trying to create a Liquidity pool for my token Progragmatically using the Raydium sdk v2. But i'm a bit confused because most articles online say you first need to create an OpenBook marketID before you create the liquidity pool.
So i want to know the difference between both of them Thank you!
